# How to optimize a Pulse-Width Pulse-Frequency (PWPF) modulated attitude control system?

Tags: attitude, design, engineering

Is the optimization process for fuel used, response time, thruster activity different? How is the trade-off between these done? Also, is there a better controller for on-off RCS thruster system?

Comment: See [Spacecraft attitude control system performance using pulse-width pulse-frequency modulated thrusters](http://calhoun.nps.edu/handle/10945/30554), R.S. McClelland, and there's one other related article in the list below the abstract. First document has pretty much everything needed to answer your question(s), and feel free to use it to self-answer, or if someone else wants to. Cheers!